# Easy way to setup vpn server/client?

Tags: vpn, pptp, pptpd

I have root access on a server and I can access my server through ssh and my server and my laptop run ubuntu. What's the easiest way to setup vpn server/client such that when I connect the vpn all of internet connections go through the server?

Comment: Here is how

https://www.linuxclever.com/2017/05/31/how-to-setup-a-pptp-vpn-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found shadowproxy super easy to use http://shadowsocks.org/en/index.html They have clients for a variety of operating systems as well.

Answer (score 4):

1. If you just want to tunnel HTTP traffic through the VPN, one of the easiest solutions would be:

   - Set up a [Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/) proxy on the server and configure it to accept only connections from localhost. See [this article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Squid) from Ubuntu community wiki.
   - On the client: tunnel the remote proxy port (by default 3128) to a local port through ssh:

     `ssh -L 3128:localhost:3128 PROXYSERVERNAME`
   - Configure your browser to use `localhost:3128` as a proxy
2. If you want all of your traffic to go through the VPN, a solution would be to setup [OpenVPN](http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html) on the server side and the use the OpenVPN Network Manager Plugin on the client to setup a connection to the server. By default, OpenVPN configured through the NetworkManager tries to tunnel all traffic through the VPN. See [another article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient) from Ubuntu community wiki.